# How to link from a group of fields in a View?

Tags: views, 8, search

I am using the [Search API module](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) in Drupal 8.6.3 and I have a page of search results displayed using Views. Each search result row consists of a number of fields.

I would like to link each whole Views row (i.e. group of fields) to the entity that the search result is referring to. How can that be done?

I have been able to link each individual field within a result back to the same found entity. However the user experience is poor because the mouseover (hover) behavior operates independently on each field in the result, implying in many cases that the link would lead to something other than the desired entity. For example in the image below my mouse was over "Category: Living Things" (hence the grey `a:hover` color). I have made it link to my "Fiji Barberi Clownfish" page but the user would probably expect it to lead to my "Living Things" page.

Ideally the whole Views row div including the white space would link to the found entity. If that's not possible then if all the text together could link to it, that would be better than the current behavior.

I have tried the [Views fieldsets module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fieldsets), but it only appears to provide the ability to style a group of fields, not link from it.

I suspect Views > Format > Settings > Field Grouping might allow this, but I am unclear how it functions and have been unable to find documentation about it.

[image]